# Controlling the 'Save Link as' option in browsers

Tags: html

I have a website with MP3 files in a page. There is an MP3 player built using HTML5. My users are able to play the songs without any problem but they are also able to download the MP3 files by using 'Save Link as' option from the browser. (Right click on MP3 'Save Link as').

I was thinking it is not possible to hide "Save Link As" until now when I ran into this page: http://www.codebasehero.com/files/music-player-1.0.1/demo/

This page has a similar player like mine (no flash). If I right click on the MP3 link, the 'Save Link as' option doesn't appear. Does anyone know how they managed to hide "Save Link as"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: the "links" on the site you mentioned are not links at all, they're `<span>` elements. There's probably some JavaScript to make they play the songs when clicked. If you check their "buy" links, those are actual links, and the browser will show the Save As option on right-click.